# Prevent the Feature Attributes dialog box in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, point

Any time I am inserting new point feature in QGIS, the Feature Attribute dialog box is popping up. Is there a way to prevent it? (I am willing to insert many points at once and this pop up box slows down the process).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - go to "Settings" -> "Options" -> "Digitizing" and tick "Suppress attribute form pop-up after feature creation".

Answer (score 4):

Some more details about this feature in QGIS, along with PyQGIS code to accomplish the same setting.

### Global setting

As @ndawson explained, this setting can be set for any feature created using QGIS.

[image: Global setting for suppress form]

#### PyQGIS

The same can be set by the following PyQGIS call:

```py
QSettings().setValue('/qgis/digitizing/disable_enter_attribute_values_dialog', True)
```

### Per layer setting

This setting **can be enable or disabled per layer**, which might be more adequate for projects with several layers. You find this setting in the layer properties.

[image: Suppress attribute form per layer]

#### PyQGIS

The same can be made by the following PyQGIS call for a specific layer `layer`:

```py
formConfig = layer.editFormConfig()
formConfig.setSuppress(1)
layer.setEditFormConfig(formConfig)
```

Comment: I amn using QGIS 3.32. I am getting this error: TypeError: QgsEditFormConfig.setSuppress(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'